# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput' even though it is clearly downloaded

Tags: python

Whenever I run the program, I get this error message.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

If I check the pip3 list I can see pynput.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Which program you run ? Pun intended

Comment: Is your interpreter setup correctly?

Comment: python -m pip install pynput

Comment: How are you running the program?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `pip3` installed `pynput` to a python installation that you are not using. For example, your `pip3` might have installed `pynput` to `python3` while your `python` refers to python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

So it works with python file.py and not with python3 file.py